# Docbook HTML Help Index

Tags: xml, xslt, chm, docbook, html-help

I have been using htmlhelp xsl to produce my htmlhelp files. Until 
yesterday, the index was there. But from today, I don't see any entry 
there in the index.hhk file. I am using xsltproc to produce my html help 
files. Here is my test xml script.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
               "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/
docbookx.dtd">
<book lang="en">
<bookinfo><title>My first DocBook document</title></bookinfo>

<chapter>
<title>TEST DOCBOOK</title>
<note>
    <title>This is Note<indexterm><primary>Note</primary></
indexterm></title>
    <para>This is test.</para>
</note>
</chapter>
<index/>
</book>
```

I used `xsltproc /usr/share/xml/docbook/stylesheet/docbook-xsl/htmlhelp/
htmlhelp.xsl test.xml` to transform my xml files to htmlhelp files.

Now my index.hhk file always looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://
                       www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft&reg; HTML Help Workshop 4.1">
<!-- Sitemap 1.0 -->
</HEAD><BODY>
<OBJECT type="text/site properties">
</OBJECT>
<UL>
</UL>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I don't know what's going wrong here. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to convert the xml file into JavaHelp files. I can see JHelpIdx.xml file was created properly.

Comment: I used `xsltproc --stringparam generate.index 1 /usr/share/xml/docbook/stylesheet/docbook-xsl/htmlhelp/htmlhelp.xsl test.xml` , but no change.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the stringparam `htmlhelp.use.hhk` to 1, if you want the hhk to be populated with extracted indexterms.

Quote from from "DocBook XSL - The Complete Guide" (http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/HtmlHelp.html#HHGenIndex)

> The htmlhelp.use.hhk parameter controls how your indexterm elements
> are converted to index entries. If htmlhelp.use.hhk is set to zero,
> then the stylesheet inserts an OBJECT element similar to the above
> example into the HTML output for each indexterm. If the parameter is
> set to 1, then the terms are instead put into the index.hhk file. You
> will still get a index.hhk file if the parameter is set to zero, but
> it will be almost empty. You can ignore the warning issued by the
> compiler about the empty file.

I've just checked it and apparently it works.

Sorry for being 5 years 4 Months late.